# How do I force homebrew to update installed software?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I have pianobar installed and I'm trying to update it using `brew update pianobar`. I also tried `brew update pianobar --force` but that didn't have any effect. It says that I have local changes, but I'm not sure how to tell it to just overwrite these.

```
From http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    Library/Formula/android-ndk.rb
    Library/Formula/android-sdk.rb
    Library/Formula/center-im.rb
    Library/Formula/putty.rb
    Library/Formula/python.rb
    ... (lines removed) ...
    Library/Formula/upx.rb
    Library/Formula/vimpager.rb
    Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    Library/Formula/tth.rb
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Updating 45bc7ad..36f4400
Aborting
Error: Failed while executing git pull http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git master
```

Comment: I think you have to use `upgrade`. `update` is for updating the formulas.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know why this happens with Homebrew when you don't do anything to mess with it, but here's how I fixed it:

1. Change to your Homebrew cellar directory `` cd `brew --cellar` ``
2. Reset git repository `git reset --hard HEAD`
3. Upgrade pianobar, at last! `brew upgrade pianobar`

FYI, `brew update` will update Homebrew to the latest version, so you may want to do that before step 3.

Comment: did 1-3 and it worked as expected, thanks! but then when i try and run pianobar it says `Login... Error: Protocol incompatible. Please upgrade libpiano.` - any thoughts? also when i tried `brew update` i get error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge: Library/Formula/tth.rb. Error: Failed while executing git pull http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git master - sorry i am new to homebrew and am really not sure what I'm doing.

Comment: Ah, git, you make life so fun!. Do `cd \`brew --prefix\`` then `git clean -f` then try `brew update`. As for the Pianobar issue, I'd try `brew upgrade libpiano` next, but I'm not using it, so I'm not certain.

Comment: that worked, thanks so much for all the help! apparently the version of libpiano that is out is not yet new enough though since I'm still getting the error even though it says everything is up to date.

Comment: Glad to help. I just installed pianobar and it works for me. I know Pandora has updated their protocol recently, but it seems Homebrew's Pianobar version is up to date. Mine is `2011.09.22`, what's yours? It should show on the first line after you run pianobar.

Answer (score 3):

As @Felix said, use `upgrade` not `update`.

If the problem comes from your dirty git tree and you just want to forget about your modifications, type `git reset --hard HEAD` before upgrading.

Comment: nothing happens when i try that... `brew upgrade pianobar -v` gives 
Kernel.exit

Comment: what do you get when you run `type -a brew`?

Comment: brew is /usr/local/bin/brew

Answer (score 1):

This is a general answer, not specific to your `pianobar` problem.

To update installed software, first update brew: `brew update`

and then upgrade the installed software: `brew upgrade`

To prevent some software from being upgraded, do `brew pin YOUR-PACKAGE-HERE`